# Looking for solutions to fix warping and seams for a tiled object wrapping around a sphere or hexagon

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with a model that is composed of tiled objects wrapped around a sphere. I'm trying to fix the warping at the poles, and have a seamless tiling effect all the way around. I'm open to trying any method that seems promising, whether it's geometry nodes, or tissuing, etc.

[image]

Comment: This could be of interest: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266773/

Comment: Try using a subdivided (subsurf) cube instead of a uv sphere. The result is slightly off spherical, but the faces all have the same size.

Answer (score 7):

A sphere can not be regularly tessellated.. A (shipped add-on: Add Mesh: Geodesic Dome)  in one of its icosaherdal forms, can produce a 'soccer-ball' approximation: hexagons with pentagonal intrusions.

Circles can be distributed on its faces..

[image]

.. scaled to face-area, if that's what you want:

[image]

Comment: Great one :) Thanks ... I haven't noticed this addon before :) Also "Face area" node I have to remember this use case :)

Comment: @vklidu what on earth was wrong with yours? I UV'd it.. I'd never heard of that add-on either.. it's a very interesting one, that may be handy for others to know about too, IMO.. If you don't have some technical reason, I'd undelete it

Comment: Thanks, but I wouldn't  :) Great if somehow useful for you (you can mentioned it in some more appropriate thread ... in this case its useless.

Comment: @vklidu OK, we'll have to agree to disagree .. :)

Comment: this is really helpful - thank you so much!