# Geometry Nodes: Phyllotaxis using Repeat Zone as a For loop

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, point-clouds

I would like to make a pattern of points following a phyllotaxis (like on a sunflower).

The algorithm I use is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
        float r = sqrt(i);
        float t = 2.4 * i;      // (137.5° to radians multiplied by i)
        float x = r * cos(t);
        float y = r * sin(t);
}
```

I would like to use the ***repeat zone*** node introduced in **Blender 4.0**.
I don’t know how to use it properly, though.

I have made a setup using the algorithm above, without the ***for loop***:
It works but I would like to do the same thing with a loop.

[image: Node Group]

[image: Set Point Position]

[image: Repeat the setup]

[image: 3D viewport]

That is the beginning of setup I have made with the ***repeat zone*** (it does not work, though):

[image: Repeat Zone try]

Does anyone have any hint?

Thank you.

(Blender 4.0)
[image]

Comment: You don't need a repeat zone for that, since the formula for each point does not depend on the data of the previous point. Your code snippet is a loop, but only because you have to iterate over all values of i. In geometry nodes however, you're always operating in a loop over all vertices, so the repeat zone is moot. You can just do this outside of a repeat zone by using the point index as the value of i.

Comment: Related: [Geometry Nodes - How to lookup a value from another geometry? (Index at Value) For Phyllotaxis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/266773/60486)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you very much @Hadriscus, no need for ***Repeat Zone*** in this case. A simple ***Point Index*** makes the job.

[image: Point Index Setup]

[image: 3D viewport]

[image]

Comment: Cool, looking good !